# Sub interface that may contain properties of parent interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to create a generic store class that has the ability to take in a partial of the generic type and merge it with the stored type.

```
  async merge(model: any): Promise<TModel | null> {
    const current = await this.providerGet();
    return await this.set({
      ...current,
      ...model
    });
  }
```

The problem i'm encountering is that i can't mark my `model` as `:TModel` because anywhere `merge({})` is used is now complaining about absent properties.

Is there a way to say that `model:any` can be an object that *may* contain 1 or more of the properties of `TModel` and still prevent it from allowing things that are not present in `TModel`?

Comment: Please consider editing this code so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).  This will increase the chance that the question will be answered and that any answer will be tested before being posted.  Good luck!  (It sounds like you want `Partial<Tmodel>` but without something I can test I can't be sure.  What type is `Tmodel`?  What is `providerGet()`?  What is `set()`?  Can you either provide typings for those or preferably replace them with something?)

Comment: do you want `async merge (model: keyof TModel) : Promise<TModel | null> { .............. }`?

Comment: @jcalz thats it! Partial was exactly what i was looking for. Now i can get type safe merges with any number of the model properties. If you make this the answer i'll mark it.